# Cannot add new line using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, newline

I am trying to edit an website, and I have tried to change the text which shown as default when the website opened. This is the code:

```js
    var l=document.location + "";
    l=l.replace(/%20/g," ");
    var index=l.indexOf('?t=');
    if(index==-1) document.location=l +"?t=Default text";
```

With this code, "Default text" will be on screen, but I want to add new lines to this, I want default text occurs on screen like

```
Default
text
```

(newline between default and text). I have tried `\n` and its derivatives, but they didn't workey, am I missing something and any suggestions?

Comment: Try `\r\n` like this `console.log("default\r\ntext");`

Comment: Newlines aren't shown in HTML, are you sure you don't just want `<br>`, just remember to URL encode ?

Comment: You can try to use `%0D%0A` as a newline character.

Comment: The solution will depend on how you are extracting and displaying the query string variable 't'. Please post the relevant code.

Comment: Use `\A` and apply `white-space: pre-wrap;` to your element.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this :

```
    var textToBeDisplayed = "default" + "<br>" + "some text";
```

Then try it in HTML like this :

```
    <p id="demo"></p>

    <script>


    var textToBeDisplayed = "some text" + "<br>" + "new line";
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = textToBeDisplayed; 
    </script>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: It didn't work for me, I cannot understand what's the problem, I have tried all of the suggestions came from you but probably the problem is coming from another parts of the code and since I downloaded it from a person's website, I cannot publish it fully, or a big part of it.
Thanks for answers and comments!

Comment: Did you try something like this ? 
**document.location=l +"?t=Default" + "<br>" + "text";**